# How can I save my CSV fe generated from a dataframe in a gitlab repo

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have wriy a python file in gitlab the file is generated when run locally but when run in gitlab it doesn't save the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `artifacts` keyword to save job artifacts in gitlab, see below

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#create-job-artifacts